# Postgre is not accepting date

Tags: php

$appdob=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['applicant_dob']));

I use this function to convert the date format supplied by the user. But days greater than 12 is not accepting. If i select 13-08-2014, Instead of supplied date, 1970-01-01 is saving in database.

Comment: How does the supplied data look like? And, how does the resulting `$appdob` look like?

Comment: i selected the date 31/08/2014. But when i look in the database, it is saved as 1970-01-01. But when i select the date 01/01/2014 it is saving.

Comment: when I put `31/08/2014` in `strtotime`, I get `1970-01-01`, using `08/31/2014` I get `2014-08-31`.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the days/months. Then it will work.

Perhaps a problem with the locale

Comment: I tried with this. But still it is saving 1970-01-01. Is there any other methods ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.

As you are using a slash `/` to separate days and months, `strtotime` expects `m/d/y`.